# SQL make continuously intervals

Tags: sql, oracle, intervals

I have mixed intervals in one table and need make from it continuously intervals. Something with analytics funtions like lead and leg?

No Pl/Sql can be used.

```
ID | BEGIN| END
1  | 1    | 2
2  | 1    | 3
3  | 2    | 4
4  | 3    | 5
5  | 4    | 9
6  | 5    | 9
```

Expected select result:

```
ID | BEGIN| END
1  | 1    | 2
2  | 2    | 3
3  | 3    | 4
4  | 4    | 5
5  | 5    | 9
```

Thanks for help.

Comment: What's your oracle version?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using actual supported oracle versions you can use `lateral` or `cross apply`:

```
--your test data:
with t(ID, BEGIN, END) as (
select 1, 1, 2 from dual union all
select 2, 1, 3 from dual union all
select 3, 2, 4 from dual union all
select 4, 3, 5 from dual union all
select 5, 4, 9 from dual union all
select 6, 5, 9 from dual
)-- end of your test data
--main query:
select 
  distinct t.id,t.begin,t.end,v.begin2,v.end2
from t
    ,lateral(select t.begin+level-1 as begin2
                  , t.begin+level as end2
             from dual
             connect by t.begin+level<=t.end)
             v
order by t.id,t.begin,t.end,v.begin2,v.end2;
```

Results:

```
        ID      BEGIN        END     BEGIN2       END2
---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
         1          1          2          1          2
         2          1          3          1          2
         2          1          3          2          3
         3          2          4          2          3
         3          2          4          3          4
         4          3          5          3          4
         4          3          5          4          5
         5          4          9          4          5
         5          4          9          5          6
         5          4          9          6          7
         5          4          9          7          8
         5          4          9          8          9
         6          5          9          5          6
         6          5          9          6          7
         6          5          9          7          8
         6          5          9          8          9

16 rows selected.
```

as you can see we just generate rows in `lateral` and calculate new begin2 and end2.
I've added original `begin` and `end` just to make it more readable. Obviusly we can omit them:

```sql
select 
  distinct t.id,v.begin2,v.end2
from t
    ,lateral(select t.begin+level-1 as begin2
                  , t.begin+level as end2
             from dual
             connect by t.begin+level<=t.end)
             v
order by t.id,v.begin2,v.end2;
```